# Aligning Rows in Jetpack Compose: Positioning Based on the First Row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, mobile-development

[image]In Android Jetpack Compose, I have three rows, and I want to position the second and third rows exactly in the same horizontal position as the first row. they should align solely based on the position of the first row.

This is the code now:

```
  Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 48.dp)
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 32.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_phone_24),
                contentDescription = null,
                )
            Text(
                text = "+11 (123) 444 555 666",

                )
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center

        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 32.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_share_24),
                contentDescription = null
            )
            Text(
                text = "@AndroidDev",

                )
        }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center

        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 32.dp),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_email_24),
                contentDescription = null
            )
            Text(
                text = "jen.doe@andorid.com",

                )
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the layout you are trying to create?

Comment: If you want three `Rows` to be aligned in `Column`, you can remove the ` .fillMaxWidth()` from all the `Rows`.

Comment: OP has set fillMaxWidth(), which make the Row from wrap_content width becomes match_parent. And then he applied horizontal as center aligned so the result is understandable

Comment: @Abhimanyu Now the rows are in the same vertical line but not centered. How can I center them with the same vertical line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

After multiple attempts with ChatGPT and Bard that provided disastrous solutions, I finally found a solution without their help by thinking outside the box in terms of Jetpack Compose:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 48.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Column{
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 32.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_phone_24),
                contentDescription = null,
            )
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 32.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_share_24),
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 32.dp),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_email_24),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
        Column{
            Text(
                text = "+11 (123) 444 555 666",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
                )
            Text(
                text = "@AndroidDev",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 16.dp),
                )
            Text(
                text = "jen.doe@andorid.com",
                )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use start for horizontalArrangement

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), 
   horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start)
```

Comment: @M Eugene Now the rows are in the same vertical line but not centered. How can I center them with the same vertical line?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not exactly right because they are not perfectly aligned. I see the text being moved more upwards especially in the third one.

This is a clean code. Try always to write clean code without being repetitive:

```
// Centered
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 32.dp),
    ) {
        RowComposable(icon = Icons.Rounded.Call, textRow = "+11 (123) 444 555 666")
        RowComposable(icon = Icons.Rounded.Share, textRow = "@AndroidDev")
        RowComposable(icon = Icons.Rounded.Email, textRow = "jen.doe@andorid.com")
    }
}
// With padding start as mentioned in my initial post
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 32.dp, start = 42.dp),
) {
    RowComposable(icon = Icons.Rounded.Call, textRow = "+11 (123) 444 555 666")
    RowComposable(icon = Icons.Rounded.Share, textRow = "@AndroidDev")
    RowComposable(icon = Icons.Rounded.Email, textRow = "jen.doe@andorid.com")
}
```

And then you can make changes in one place only:

```
@Composable
fun RowComposable(
    icon: ImageVector,
    textRow: String
) {
    Column {
        Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = null)
            Spacer(Modifier.width(32.dp))
            Text(
                text = textRow
            )
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
    }
}
```

**Example image:**

[image]

Comment: My solution is perfect; you should try it before making negative comments. Your solution isn't working; I checked it.

Comment: My friend I am not here to write negative comments, I am writing it because somebody might find it helpful...

Comment: I have added image to see on your own that it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand you correctly.
Thank you for sharing this solution; I checked it again and found it better than mine.