# Centering Jetpack composables in UI horizontally, while maintaining left alignment within the composable itself

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to complete a codelab for Jetpack Compose Basics, and there's a challenge for which they don't provide the code solution, and I'm stumped. I have read countless other StackOverflow posts and blogs (and official docs) about how to potentially use Spacer, or horizontalAlignment, or the .weight modifier, and no matter what I do, I can either get everything centered (but no left align), or everything left aligned at the left edge of the screen, but not centered. I did come up with a solution using a combo of Spacers + .weight modifier that gave me what I want, but it doesn't scale to different screen sizes. This seems like it should be WAY easier than it is, so I assume I'm doing something wrong.

Here's what I am trying to build:
[image: Contact Card - Centered in UI, with Left Justification within]

And here is the code that gets me "everything centered":

```
@Composable
fun ContactInfo(phone_text: String, social_text: String, email_text: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.android_logo)
    Column (
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    )
    {
        Row (
        ){
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Phone,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.phone_android_content_desc),
                tint = Color(0xff056c3a),
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(end=16.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = phone_text,
                fontSize = 12.sp
            )
        }
        Row (
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Share,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.phone_android_content_desc),
                tint = Color(0xff056c3a),
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(end=16.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = social_text,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
            )
        }
        Row (
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Email,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.phone_android_content_desc),
                tint = Color(0xff056c3a),
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(end=16.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = email_text,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
            )
        }

    }
}
```

That yields this:
[image: Everything Centered]

And here is the code using Spacers & .weight that gives me sort of what I want, but doesn't scale to different screen sizes:

```
@Composable
fun ContactInfo(phone_text: String, social_text: String, email_text: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.android_logo)
    Column (
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    )
    {
        Row (
        ){
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(.5F))
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Phone,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.phone_android_content_desc),
                tint = Color(0xff056c3a),
                modifier = modifier
                    .weight(.25F)
            )
            Text(
                modifier = modifier.weight(1F),
                text = phone_text,
                fontSize = 12.sp
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(.5F))
        }
        Row (
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(.5F))
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Share,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.phone_android_content_desc),
                tint = Color(0xff056c3a),
                        modifier = modifier
                            .weight(.25F)
            )
            Text(
                modifier = modifier.weight(1F),
                text = social_text,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(.5F))
        }
        Row (
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(.5F))

            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Email,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.phone_android_content_desc),
                tint = Color(0xff056c3a),
                        modifier = modifier
                            .weight(.25F)
            )
            Text(
                text = email_text,
                modifier = modifier.weight(1F),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(.5F))
        }
    }
}
```

That yields this:
[image: Left Justified & Centered, but doesn't scale]

Comment: You can have a look on my answer for a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248841/6805392

Answer (score 2):

You have to just wrap all `Row`s within a `Column`.

Example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ContactInfo(
    // ...
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column (
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Column {
            Row {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Phone, contentDescription = "")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Text(text = "+11 (123) 444 555 666")
            }
            Row {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Share, contentDescription = "")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Text(text = "@AndroidDev")
            }
            Row {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Email, contentDescription = "")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Text(text = "jen.doe@android.com")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa!!! That is amazing. And I understand why it works, but I would not have thought of that. Is this a very common pattern when building UI (needing to have an extra "container" purely to control additional styling of a group?)

Comment: @rsilverst Yes, more than common ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try.

```
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        CustomBottomBar()
    }
) { paddingValues ->
    // your content
    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues))
}
```

Views

```
@Composable
fun CustomBottomBar() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
            .background(
                color = Color(210, 232, 213)
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(top = 80.dp)

        ) {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                InfoRow(
                    text = "+11 (123) 444 555 666",
                    icon = Icons.Default.Phone
                )
                InfoRow(
                    text = "@AndroidDev",
                    icon = Icons.Default.Share
                )
                InfoRow(
                    text = "john.doe@android.com",
                    icon = Icons.Default.Email
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun InfoRow(text: String, icon: ImageVector) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = icon,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color(1, 109, 59)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))

        Text(text = text)
    }
}
```

[image: Output]